# Intercontainer communication with Apache Tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, networking, war

Is intercontainer communication possible within Apache tomcat?

For example: 
Say you have 2 rest services and a Java EE project. Your Java EE project calls the services at the URL where the same hosting server is at.

Is it possible for Apache Tomcat to eliminate the extra call out of the webserver and just send it direct to the service's container instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Tomcat can't do this. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. 
However, why not build a strategy pattern for communication that can be configured to either use HTTP calls, or to call via Beans?

Comment: I was just looking for a scalable way of managing separated services and projects.